# How to pass a 2D vector to a function using pass-by-reference C++

Tags: c++, function, structure, 2d-vector

```
struct st
{
    int to, cost;
};

void fun(vector<st>&v1[10])
{
    vector<st>v2[10];
    v1=v2;
}

int main()
{
    vector<st>arr[10];
    fun(arr);
}
```

I want to pass a 2D vector in a function by reference and swap the vector with another vector in that function. But I am getting error. I don't want to do it with pair vector. I want to use structure here. How to do it?

[here is a screenshot of my error messege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxivE.png)

Comment: You have an array of 10 vectors. Why are you mixing the types? Why not a `std::vector<std::vector<st>>`?

Comment: The immediate error is that `vector<st>&  v1[10]` is an array of references. A reference to an  array would look like `vector<st> (&v1)[10]`. All of this can be avoided by *not* using C style arrays in the first place.

Comment: I agree with @CoryKramer: What you present here is nominally not a "2D vector" but a bastard: A 1D array of 1D vectors (which *logically* is a 2D data structure).

Answer (score 4):

One major problem: When passing an array as an argument, what is really passed is a *pointer*.

It can easily be solved by using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
void fun(std::array<std::vector<st>, 10>& v1)
{
    std::array<std::vector<st>, 10> v2;
    // Initialize v2...
    v1 = v2;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::vector<st>, 10> arr;
    fun(arr);
}
```

---

After introducing `std::array`above, I would rather recommend *returning* the array instead of passing by reference:

```
std::array<std::vector<st>, 10> fun()
{
    std::array<std::vector<st>, 10> v2;
    // Initialize v2...
    return v2;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::vector<st>, 10> arr = fun();
}
```

Comment: An array is only passed as a pointer if the function is expecting one. If the function is expecting a reference to an array, the reference is passed instead. An example would be the OP's code with proper parentheses as suggested by Bo Persson.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider True, but then we have the problem of the assignment `v1 = v2`. C-style arrays can not be assigned. `std::array` solves that problem as well.